# Why Kibana is not able authenticate Elasticsearch server because of security?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana-7

I am trying to deploy Elasticsearch and Kibana on the k8s cluster. I simply deploy Elasticsearch and Kibna it works perfectly. Then I try to add security by adding a username and password. Elasticsearch works fine when I search the URL it asks username and password and then I can see API. However, by visiting service Kibna URL I see **Kibana server is not ready yet**. I check the Pod logs and I found this error.

```
box provides an additional layer of protection, but is not supported for Linux CentOS 8.5.2111\n OS. Automatically setting 'xpack.reporting.capture.browser.chromium.disableSandbox: true'."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-03-28T12:10:24+00:00","tags":["error","elasticsearch-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND elasticsearch"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-03-28T12:10:53+00:00","tags":["warning","process"],"pid":7,"message":"Error [ProductNotSupportedSecurityError]: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to security privileges on the server side. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product.\n    at /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:576:19\n    at onBody (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:369:9)\n    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:291:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-03-28T12:10:54+00:00","tags":["error","elasticsearch-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]"}
```

It seems like Kibana is not able to access Elasticsearch even though I provided the username and password in the deployment file.

**Elastic.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
#namespace: logging
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.1
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
          - name: ELASTIC_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: elasticsearch-credentials
                key: username
          - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: elasticsearch-credentials
                key: password
          - name: xpack.security.enabled
            value: "true"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "openebs-hostpath"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 3Gi
```

**Kibana.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
#namespace: logging
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
            value: http://elastic:admin!@elasticsearch:9200
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFICATIONMODE
            value: none
          - name: ELASTIC_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: elasticsearch-credentials
                key: username
          - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: elasticsearch-credentials
                key: password
          - name: xpack.security.enabled
            value: "true"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
```

**What I have done**: I try to use the actual URL of Elasticsearch and found the same error. When I exec into the Kibana pod and try to curl the URL `http://elastic:admin!@elasticsearch:9200`
I can access the API and see the result.

**What do I want:** I want to fix this issue. Can you please tell me where exactly I made mistake? Why Kibana is not ready?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `elastic` user for Kibana authentication after elasticsearch v8.

**EDIT:**
use [built-in users](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#set-built-in-user-passwords) like kibana_system.

You can create a password for the **kibana_system** user with the following command

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive
```

**OR**

Create a token with the following command and use that.

```
bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/create-enrollment-token.html

Comment: I am not using V8 I am using 7.16.1

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, It must be earlier than v8. But the problem is you are trying to use elastic user in kibana.yml and it's not allowed.

Comment: What is the solution to that? How can I set up Kibana and elastic on k8s with security? I set up this on docker and it worked perfectly. I created ENV under kibana file.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with the k8s env file because I don't know.